# Angular: on form change event

Tags: angular, typescript

I have form group in my angular app.
Since I would like to aviod writing onChange for each form element, my idea was to subscribe to entire form changes, and then on event check changed element

So this is relevant part of the code:

```
constructor(){
this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  ...
});

this.event$ = this.orderForm.valueChanges.subscribe((x:any) => {
  console.log('form value changed')
  console.log(x)
});
```

Problem is, this x is just entire form so I have no idea what element is changed

Is there any smart way to find out what form element changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"stolen" the idea of AT82, we can has a recursive function that return an observable. Well, instead of use "tap", we can use map to return an object with two properties: name (the control has changed) and value.

So some like

```
  mergeForm(form: FormGroup | FormArray, suffix: string) {
    if (form instanceof FormArray) {
      console.log(suffix)
      const formArray = form as FormArray;
      const arr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < formArray.controls.length; i++) {
        const control = formArray.at(i);
        arr.push(
          control instanceof FormGroup
            ? this.mergeForm(control, suffix + i+'.')
            : control.valueChanges.pipe(
                map((value) => ({ name: suffix + i, value: value }))
              )
        );
      }
      return merge(...arr);
    }
    return merge(
      ...Object.keys(form.controls).map((controlName: string) => {
        const control = form.get(controlName);
        return control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray
          ? this.mergeForm(control, suffix + controlName + '.')
          
          : control.valueChanges.pipe(
              map((value) => ({ name: suffix + controlName, value: value }))
            );
      })
    );
  }
```

We can call in the way

```
this.mergeForm(this.orderForm, '')
  .pipe(takeWhile((_) => this.alive))
  .subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

You can see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l2pi3z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: If you don't use FormArray you can simply the recursive function

Answer (score 2):

I don't thing there is a function that returns only the formControls that have changed.

But since valueChanges is an observeable you could use `pairwise` to get the previous and the next value. And compare them to find out what has changed.

```
this.orderForm.valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(null), pairwise())
  .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => ... );
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but it's kind of not what I'm trying to do. Looping through 50+ elements on multiple levels on every change (and there are multiple text inputs, that means it's whole loop for each letter), comparing them to other form, just seems like overdoing things. Guess my best option is then single change function that gets formelement name and ngModelChange in every form field

Answer (score 2):

This works well if you have a simple form with just formcontrols, no nested groups or FormArrays.

You can use rxjs `merge` for each form controls value changes and figure out which one changed:

```ts
merge(
  ...Object.keys(this.orderForm.controls).map(
    (controlName: string) =>
      this.orderForm.get(controlName).valueChanges.pipe(
        tap((value) => {
          console.log(`Control "${controlName}" changed. New value: ${value}`)
        })
      )
  )
).subscribe();
```

Here's a **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dg3hcw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your reference.

Comment: Thanks but my form has nested groups, otherwise nice solution