# How to do calculation for two form fields in angular and patch it

Tags: javascript, html, angular

[ReferenceImage][1]

->Hello, I need to do the calculation for two fields look at the reference image once.

->In the basic pay field if I enter 100 and in Gst % on the first premium amount if I enter 5 then automatically in the first premium amount 105 value should display calculation is like (100+5%100 = 105).

->same if I enter 5 in GST % on next premium amount 105 should be displayed in the next premium amount field.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNtAa.png

Answer (score 5):

It's a problem very common to have a form with some "calculated value".

In Angular we has two aproach to mannage forms: Reactive Forms (the formGroup and FormControl) or Template driven form (the [(ngModel)])

If we use [(ngModel)] we can store the calculate value in a variable (or not). If we use FormGroup we can store the calculate value in a FormControl of the FormGroup or not. Really it's unnecessary store the value calculate. We can make, e.g.

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input name="cant" [(ngModel)]="cant" />
  <input name="porc" [(ngModel)]="porc" />
  <input name="result" readonly [ngModel]="(+cant * +porc) / 100" />
</form>
{{f.value|json}} <---just to check


//in .ts
cant:number=0;
porc:number=0;
```

or

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="cant">
  <input formControlName="porc">
  <input readonly [ngModel]="+form.value.cant*(+form.value.porc)/100" 
                  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
</form>
{{form?.value|json}} <--just to check

//in .ts
  form=new FormGroup({
    cant:new FormControl(0),
    porc:new FormControl(0)
  })
```

See that always need convert to number the "values". It's the reason to add the **+** to the values. See also that the only code in .ts is declare the variables or declare the formGroup

I use a input readonly, but you can use a span or a div

Well, if we want to store the result in a variable -or in a FormControl of the formGroup we need make some changes

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <input name="cant" [ngModel]="cant" 
         (ngModelChange)="cant=+$event;calculateResult()" />
    <input name="porc" [(ngModel)]="porc" 
         (ngModelChange)="porc=+$event;calculateResult()"/>
    <input name="result" readonly [ngModel]="result" />
</form>
{{f.value|json}}

//in .ts
//add a new variable
result:number=0
//and add the function calculateResult
calculateResult(){
   this.result=this.cant*this.porc/100
}
```

See how "split" the [(ngModel)] in [ngModel] and (ngModelChange).

Using reactive form

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="cant" (input)="calculateResultForm()" />
  <input formControlName="porc" (input)="calculateResultForm()"/>
  <input readonly formControlName="result" />
  />
</form>

//in .ts
  form=new FormGroup({
    cant:new FormControl(0),
    porc:new FormControl(0),
    result:new FormControl(0) //<--we add this FormControl
  })
  //and the function
  calculateResultForm()
  {
    this.form.get('result').setValue(
         +this.form.value.cant*(+this.form.value.porc)/100)
  }
```

Well, in reactiveForms is common use the observable [valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) instead of using the event input. valueChanges are an observable. This mean that you can subscribe to changes (in ngOnInit). e.g. we can do

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.form.get('cant').valueChanges.subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.calculateResultForm()
   })
   this.form.get('porc').valueChanges.subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.calculateResultForm()
   })
}

  calculateResultForm()
  {
    //see that in this case we can NOT use
    //this.form.value.cant and this.form.value.porc
    //because the value is with the old values

    const cant=+this.form.get('cant').value
    const porc=+this.form.get('porc').value
    this.form.get('result').setValue(cant*porc/100)
  }
```

Well the "problem" with the observables is that we need unsubscribe in ngDestroy of the component, so we declare two variables

```
   sub1:Subscription
   sub2:Subcription
```

When use the valueChanges we use

```
    this.sub1=this.form.get('cant').valueChanges.subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.calculateResultForm()
   })
   this.sub2=this.form.get('porc').valueChanges.subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.calculateResultForm()
   })
```

And in ngOnDestroy we write

```
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.sub1.unsubscribe()
    this.sub2.unsubscribe()
  }
```

Well really nobody subscribe each FormControl, generally we use an rxjs operator to create an unique subcription.

We can use rxjs operator `merge`. don't worry it's only put the values changes separated by commas

```
    this.sub1=merge(
      this.form.get('cant').valueChanges,
      this.form.get('porc').valueChanges
    ).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.calculateResultForm()
   })
```

Others ways are use forkJoin or similar, use takeUntil or takeWhile to unsubscribe automatically, etc. but this answer is yet a bit large

NOTE: I know that the first time you meet ReactiveForms and Observables scare a few. Really they are a powerful tool and we need understand a bit about they

If you get the final of the answer, great!, you can check the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ycrqvq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular reactive forms, you can use the patchValue() method of the FormGroup.

You can refer the document link: [Angular document for reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model)

In your case you can call the patchValue method onKeyPress.

Comment: i know about methods i am not getting the exact logic help me with logic

Comment: I made a demo app on stackblitz. I hope this is what you are looking for :) I know the code is not very optimized, its just a quick implementation of what I think you need.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zolsvv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @domnicfernandes, you're using Angular, not javascript or jQuery, so avoid use `(keyup)`. If you're using ReactiveForms, subcribe to valueChanges of the formControl, if you use template driven form -ngModel- use variables

Comment: @Eliseo I checked your answer. It looks much more elegant and angular way of doing it. Thanks for pointing that out.